# Laravel 5.4 set different locale for each routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 sections user and admin for the route. Now I want to set the language separately. User => fr, and admin => id.

admin.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('ADMIN_DOMAIN'), 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
    App::setLocale('en');

    //other routes
}
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('ROOT_DOMAIN'), 'namespace' => 'User'], function () {
    App::setLocale('fr');

    //other routes
}
```

The problem with this, all myapplication become using `fr` lang instead of `en`.

How can I separate their language without major change all the route (not putting prefix at front)?

---

My current solution is make middleware and pass additional argument to the middleware. maybe you guys have any other great idea?

Comment: What is your default language in config/app.php

Comment: @AmitKumar `fr` is default.

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia any example on laravel docs? or I should set manually on the session?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/set-locale-with-middleware-in-laravel-5 also https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale

Comment: i think you should check App::isLocale('fr') and set for App::setLocale() that should do the trick

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia thanks for the link. but it append prefix at front, the problem is my app will do a major change if I append it (need to fix every single link).

Comment: @AmitKumar if you just use App::setLocale() it will return error. because it expect an argument

Comment: I don't know a solution out of the box but you can look for a middleware `\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class`

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia yes. right now my only solution is add new middleware and pass argument to it

Comment: Yes by that way you can easily manage things